# Would have been... vs. Had been

Tags: meaning, word-choice, conditionals, would-have-been

I just saw this sentence on cnn:

**Experts believe if Friday's test *would have* been fired on a flatter, standard trajectory, it could have threatened cities like Los Angeles, Denver and Chicago.**

I expected this:

**Experts believe if Friday's test  *had been* fired on a flatter, standard trajectory, it could have threatened cities like Los Angeles, Denver and Chicago.**

So what is the difference between these two sentences in terms of meaning and grammar?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest "Experts believe if Friday's test ***could*** have been fired on a flatter, standard trajectory, it ***would*** have threatened cities like Los Angeles, Denver and Chicago"

Comment: There is the same distortion in French: "Si j'aurais su" instead of "Si j'avais su", je ne serais pas venu" : "If I would have known I would not have come." Laziness is everywhere  :-)

Comment: @Weather Vane You're suggesting a very different meaning from that intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an American regionalism that seems to be slowly spreading.

[Here](https://www.grammarly.com/answers/questions/94768-would-have-vs-had/) is a question/answer on it from Grammerly, which speculates that it will become widely accepted sometime in the not-too-distant future.

It's not terribly uncommon in the U.S., it's wrong in standard English, and it really annoys some people. The right way to say this would be *had been*, as you surmise:

> Experts believe if Friday's test had been fired on a flatter, standard trajectory, it could have threatened cities like Los Angeles, Denver and Chicago.

But if you listen to Americans, you'll run into *would have been* fairly often, and if the speaker comes from a region where it's used, you might have a hard time convincing them that it's incorrect.

Comment: [Jane Straus](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/verbs/if-i-would-have-vs-if-i-had/) wasn't a fan.

Comment: @Edwin: Yup. To older speakers, this probably sounds a bit like split infinitives sounded to older speakers back in the 1850s—a dreadful abomination committed against the English language by the younger generations.

Comment: Can you provide source for "it's wrong in standard English?" Sounds fine to me. Clearly you're wrong about it *becoming* accepted as it is already extremely widely accepted.

Comment: Nevermind. Other answer explained what you failed to.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce: [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wish+it+had%2C+wish+it+would+have%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cwish+it+would+have%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwish%20it%20had%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwish%20it%20would%20have%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwish%20it%20would%20have%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) shows that *I wish it would have* it is still quite rare in comparison to the "correct" form, *I wish it had*. But you can see that in the U.S., it's being used more and more frequently. Not so much in the U.K.

Answer (score 2):

When talking about something in the past that didn't happen, you use the past perfect tense in the if clause (...if Friday's test ***had*** ***been***...) and the conditional perfect in the then clause (...it ***would have*** threatened...).

CNN used the conditional perfect tense in the if clause, which is incorrect. The correct use of the conditional perfect tense is when it's used in the `then` clause :

Experts believe cities like Los Angeles, Denver and Chicago **would have been** threatened if Friday's test had been fired on a flatter, standard trajectory

OR (what you expected)

Experts believe if Friday's test had been fired on a flatter, standard trajectory, [then] it ***would have*** threatened cities like Los Angeles, Denver and Chicago.

[If I Would Have... vs. If I Had...](http://www.grammarbook.com/newsletters/071012.htm)

Comment: Why ***would*** and not ***could***? They're both grammatical, although they mean slightly different things. And ***could*** was the original wording.

Comment: +1 you're right, i had my could(s) and would(s) switched around and could was the original wording.

Comment: It's not really useful in these kind of questions to say something is "correct" or "incorrect."  If you're writing your dissertation you should avoid this construction, I suppose, but using the "correct" form in conversation often sounds needlessly stilted to my ears.

Comment: Ironically, the existence of scolding articles about this form is a testament to its widespread use.